# Не отображаются графики

Tags: javascript, диаграммы, highcharts

В series один график нормально выполняется рандомно,а второй не работает . Где может быть ошибка?

```js
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            },
            lang: {
                loading: 'Загрузка...',
                months: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
                weekdays: ['Воскресенье', 'Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда', 'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота'],
                shortMonths: ['Янв', 'Фев', 'Март', 'Апр', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Авг', 'Сент', 'Окт', 'Нояб', 'Дек'],
                exportButtonTitle: "Экспорт",
                printButtonTitle: "Печать",
                rangeSelectorFrom: "С",
                rangeSelectorTo: "По",
                rangeSelectorZoom: "Период",
                downloadCSV: 'Скачать CSV',
                downloadXLS: 'Скачать XLS',
            }
        });
  

  
        Highcharts.chart('chart1', {
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                }
            },

            time: {
                useUTC: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Гистограмма 1',
                style: {
                    color: 'black',
                    fontSize: '20px',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'

                },
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150,
                style: {
                    color: 'black',
                    fontSize: '15px',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                //For time series, x-axis labels will be time

                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: 'black',
                        fontSize: '15px',
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    },
                    //You can format the label according to your need
                    format: '{value:%H:%M:%S}',
                },
            },
            yAxis: {
                "fontSize": '21px',
                offset: 30,
                color: 'black',
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
                tickInterval: 1,
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '14px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',

                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
                pointFormat: '{point.x:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}<br/>{point.y:.2f}'
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Значения1',
                data: (function() {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: Math.random()
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                }())
            }, {
                name: 'Значения2',
                data: (function() {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: Math.random()
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                }())
            }, ]
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="pag_ch1" style="width:100%;display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center">
        <div id="chart1" style="height: 600px; width: 1800px;margin-top: 100px"></div><a href="#" class="but1">К ГРАФИКУ</a>

    </div>
```

Comment: в смысле? изначально показывается оба графика. далее по таймеру значения добавляются только в один из них. в чем проблема?

Comment: А во второй тогда почему не добавляются ,в чем загвоздка?

Comment: дак вы посмотрите на функцию, описанную в `chart -> events -> load`, там работа только с `series[0]`. Как написано, так и работает.

Comment: Можете код подправить чтоб графики стоились равномерно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на событие загрузки данных `chart.events.load`, данные по таймеру добавляются только в первую серию.

```
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            events: {
                load: function() {
                    var series = this.series;
                    setInterval(function() {
                        var x  = (new Date()).getTime(), 
                            y  = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
                            y2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);

                        series[0].addPoint([x, y],  true, true);
                        series[1].addPoint([x, y2], true, true);
                    }, 3000);
                }
            }
        },
```

сохраните ссылку на массив серий в целом, и добавляйте значения в обе.

*замечу, что в исходных данных серий, у вас там может случится, что точки двух серий будут попадать в разные секунды, так как `getTime` вызывается два раза к текущему времени, а не берется одно начальное.*

Comment: спасибо огромное )